# API keys remain empty

Tags: servicestack

I refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292099/authenticate-server-to-server-communication-with-api-key/43292283#43292283). I try to create a server account if it does not exist when the server starts. I have overwritten `OnAfterInit` to do this. Unfortunately no keys are created and worse, my ApiKeyAuthProvider seems to be null! Here is the code:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    private PooledRedisClientManager RedisBusPool { get; set; }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        RedisBusPool = new PooledRedisClientManager(connStrBus);

        #region IOC registrations
        container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(connStrBus));
        container.Register(c => new RedisAuthRepository(RedisBusPool));
        //...
        #endregion


        #region ServiceStack plugins
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), 
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new BediCredentialsAuthProvider(),
                new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings)
                {
                    KeyTypes = new []{"secret", "publishable"},
                },
            }
        ));
        //...

        #endregion
        //...
    }

    public override void OnAfterInit()
    {
        #region Add test users
        var authRepo = TryResolve<RedisAuthRepository>();
        var user = authRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName("JoeTest");
        if (user == null)
        {
            var newUser = new UserAuth();
            newUser.UserName = "JoeTest";
            newUser.Email = "Joe@test.com";
            newUser.FirstName = "Joe";
            newUser.LastName = "Test";
            user = authRepo.CreateUserAuth(newUser, "topSecret!");
        }

        var keys = authRepo.GetUserApiKeys(user.Id.ToString());
        foreach (var apiKey in keys)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(apiKey);
        }

        //CANT GET THE AUTHPROVIDER IT IS ALWAYS NULL HERE
        var authProvider = (ApiKeyAuthProvider)AuthenticateService.GetAuthProvider(ApiKeyAuthProvider.Name);


        #endregion
        base.OnAfterInit();
    }

}
```

The user is successfully created with password, salt etc. Here is what my Redis database shows:

```
{
  "__type": "ServiceStack.Auth.UserAuth, ServiceStack",
  "Id": 2,
  "UserName": "JoeTest",
  "Email": "Joe@test.com",
  "FirstName": "Joe",
  "LastName": "Test",
  "Salt": "1/696g==",
  "PasswordHash": "FZNI5cR5TWTpbvvm9PDy/w/JdRZImQYU5m5P6z8j7TY=",
  "DigestHa1Hash": "e4e0cff88386c6f991d13a3802ce7b53",
  "Roles": [],
  "Permissions": [],
  "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1491811177540)\/",
  "ModifiedDate": "\/Date(1491811177540)\/",
  "InvalidLoginAttempts": 0
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How are the API key created? What am I missing or does this only work with the `RegistrationFeature`enabled? If so, how can I protect this (self-registration is not allowed in my scenario) and how can I use it after the initialization of my service?
2. I was browsing a bit through the code of RedisAuthRepository.cs and found this:

   `var saltedHash = HostContext.Resolve<IHashProvider>();`

Does this mean that I can implement and plug-in my own HashProvider? If so how does that work?

**UPDATE**

I figured out that I can assign keys but only if I put the code into `AfterInitCallbacks.Add`. It seems to be called AFTER `OnAfterInit()`.

So this code creates the key for the account generated during ServiceStartup:

```
AfterInitCallbacks.Add(host =>
{

    var authProvider = (ApiKeyAuthProvider)AuthenticateService.GetAuthProvider(ApiKeyAuthProvider.Name);
    var authRepo = (IManageApiKeys)TryResolve<RedisAuthRepository>();
    var userRepo = (IUserAuthRepository)TryResolve<RedisAuthRepository>();
    var user = userRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName("JoeTest");

    var keys = authRepo.GetUserApiKeys(user.Id.ToString());
    if (keys.Count == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            keys = authProvider.GenerateNewApiKeys(user.Id.ToString());
            authRepo.StoreAll(keys);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
});
```

At least I can see what is generated on Redis now. However it remains unclear to me **how keys can be created automatically**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should also only have one `PooledRedisClientManager` singleton instance to pool all your connections together so you should also change your Redis Client Manager connection to reuse the same instance, e.g:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => RedisBusPool);
```

User Auth Repositories should be registered against the `IAuthRepository` interface so it can be resolved, so you'll need to change it to:

```
container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c => new RedisAuthRepository(RedisBusPool));
```

Which you'd now retrieve with:

```
var authRepo = (IUserAuthRepository)TryResolve<IAuthRepository>();
```

As for retrieving the `ApiKeyAuthProvider`, I've confirmed that this works as expected:

```
 var authProvider = (ApiKeyAuthProvider)
     AuthenticateService.GetAuthProvider(ApiKeyAuthProvider.Name);
```

If you've registered `ApiKeyAuthProvider` in AuthFeature as shown it should be returned. I would double-check that the Null Reference Error isn't due to another issue.

Comment: Thanks, Demis. I just updated my original post. I just make the corrections in your answer.

Comment: @ThommyB I don't know what you mean by **created automatically**? Calling `StoreAll()` is what creates the API Keys.

Comment: I mean that keys are created with the creation of the user, so I do not have to call `StoreAll()`. The docs say: 'Whilst the API Key Auth Provider will automatically generate API Keys for new users, if .....'

Comment: @ThommyB It gets created when a a [new User is registered](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/f9f7f4b908de22462dcdf0f9a1ce795309cb792a/src/ServiceStack/Auth/ApiKeyAuthProvider.cs#L399) (e.g. using /register Service). But if you're not using the built-in Register Service you can [Raise your own OnRegistered() AuthEvents instead](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/f9f7f4b908de22462dcdf0f9a1ce795309cb792a/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs#L150-L151).

Comment: Ah as I expected. Since auto-registration is not an option in this project, I will look into the AuthEvents. I made the changes you mentioned in your answer and now I can confirm it works no matter whether I implement it in `OnAfterInit` or `AfterInitCallbacks`.